# Find referenceContainer in Magento 2.1 module

Tags: magento-2.1, module, layout, template, containers

This is my first attempt to write a Module for Magento 2.1 I have read the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html) for `referenceContainer` that is not very helpful,

I would like to know how can I access and apply my change in a specific div in my template, following is the code of template of another module where I would like to inject my code

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column main"> 

    <div class="wk-mp-design">
      <div class="wk-mp-design-inner wk-mp-design-inner-last">
        <div class="wk-mp-profile-container storename">
          <div class="store-name">About Store</div>
        </div>
        <span class="data"></span>
        <div class="wk-mp-profile-container storename wk-mp-display-block-css">
          <div class="store-name">On the Social Web</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I would Like to add the information beneath `<div class="store-name">About Store</div>` or with in `<span class="data"></span>` or above `<span class="data"></span>` what ever is doable for now

I have following xml in layout for this injection

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/e$
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="App\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

now with `name="content"` it injects the html right before the end of `<div class="column main">` how do I identify the correct container to inject html using `referenceContainer`

Comment: Where you need to add those content ?Do you need to ad in footer?

Comment: If you see the html in my question above, I want to see the content below `<div class="store-name">About Store</div>` line